# Automatic Proxy Class

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, macros, proxy-classes

Assume I have an interface

```
class I{
public:
    virtual void f(int id)=0;
    virtual void g(int id, float x)=0;
}
```

I need a proxy class, to do some sort of id to pointer mapping

```
class Proxy : I
{
    I * i[5];
public:
    void f(int id)
    {
        i[id]->f(id);
    }

    void g(int id, float x)
    {
        i[id]->g(id, x);
    }

}
```

So when i write

```
Proxy *p;
p->f(1);
```

f is called on the object with id=1

there are several such cases and interfaces are rather large.
So I don't want to code all the functions in the proxy class.
Is there way to do it automatically? maybe using macros, templates, overloading "->" etc.

Comment: Are there many interfaces you write the same proxy for, or many proxy classes for the same interface, or many proxies for many interfaces?

Comment: it's a bit confusing: it looks like that and instance of I does not know his own index, but it gets to know when his f or g methods are called... why? weird design. I would plan the whole thing with I never knowing his own index. That would make a better sense.

Comment: @hansmaad, many proxies for many interfaces (one-to-one)

Comment: @LorenzoPistone, it's not important for this question.  instances of I do not need to know its id. It's just for convenience. i.e.: one interface for both id-manager (Proxy) and I objects.

Comment: I don't think there's a clean solution. My best thought is to differentiate the behavior of the I class, so if one of its object is created with a certain flag, it rather works as a proxy of other instances of itself. You'll have to put a little code, at the beginning of each member function, that checks if the current instance is a proxy, and if so call the same method on the requested instance. That could be done with macros.

Comment: What's wrong with `p->get(i)->f()`?

Comment: You might be able to write a tool that writes the proxy classes for you without too much trouble.  Perhaps use SWIG to parse the interfaces to XML, and then write a Java program that parses that XML and writes the appropriate proxy class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easy solution is to define an operator-> that returns the pointer to the interface. But this will break your encapsulation since everybody can access your objects directly and you actually don't need your proxy class (you might as well just use a std::map).

Alternative you could do something like

```
template <typename Interface>
class Proxy
{
   Interface* interfaces[5];
public:
  template <typename F, typename... Params>
  auto operator()(F f, const int id,  Params... parameters)
           -> decltype((interfaces[id]->*f)(id, parameters...))
  { return (interfaces[id]->*f)(id, parameters...); }
};
```

It heavily relies on C++11 features so it might not compile with your compiler.

First it uses the Variadic templates. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_Templates for more information.

Next it uses decl_type. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype for more information.

You have to use it like this:

```
  Proxy<I> p;
  ...

  p(&I::f,1);
  p(&I::g,3, 1.);
```

Comment: woow! we don't have a C++11 compatible compiler but, this is just beautiful! Thank you!

Comment: well, i guess this is the best i can get :)

Comment: don't we need `std::forward<Param>(params...)...`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is suitable for you, but you could take care of this using pointers to functions...

ie.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*f)(int);

void f1(int a)
{
    printf("f1: %d\n", a);
}
void f2(int a)
{
    printf("f2: %d\n", a);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    f array[5] = {NULL}; // create array of pointers
    array[0] = f1; // assign different functions on them
    array[1] = f2; // -||-

    array[0](10); // call them
    array[1](12);

    // and you end up with something like "array[i]();" in your proxy class...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Yet another solution.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/857329ab4433a3a9

```
  #include <iostream>

  template <class F, class... Args>
  inline decltype(auto) invoke(F&& f, Args&&... args) 
     //-> decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
  { 
    return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }

  int main()
  {
     using namespace std;

     cout<<"hello"<<endl;

     struct RaiiProxy {
        RaiiProxy(){
           cout<<"RaiiProxy in"<<endl;
        }
        ~RaiiProxy(){
           cout<<"RaiiProxy out"<<endl;
        }
     };
     auto proxy = [](auto&&f,auto&&...args){
        RaiiProxy raii;
        return invoke( forward<decltype(f)>(f), std::forward(args)... );
     };

     // Use as function
     proxy( [](){ cout<<"I am in proxy."<<endl; } );

     // Use raii
     {  RaiiProxy raii;
        cout<<"I am in RaiiProxy."<<endl;
     }

     cout<<"bye."<<endl;
  }
```